# Webpack script-loader vs. imports-loader?module=>false

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm trying include jquery (and other legacy libs) into a webpack project.

I need the jquery to be available globally, also in HTML.

There are so many options to achieve this, but here are 2 I came up with:

**Option 1.**

```
// webpack.config.js
module: {
    noParse: /jquery/,
    rules: [
        {
            test: /jquery/,
            use: ['imports-loader?module=>false']
        }
    ]
},

// entrypoint.js
import 'jquery';
```

**Option 2.**

```
// webpack.config.js
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /jquery/,
            use: ['script-loader']
        }
    ]
},

// entrypoint.js
import 'jquery';
```

Which of these would be better (Or some other method?)

Both of these seem to work identically, however I think option 1 would be better since script-loader (option 2) uses eval.